# Clear a react state field before refreshing with new data from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux-firebase

[image]

The screenshot is from State.Firestore.ordered.trainings in the console. Let's say exampleA.js has the following codes of

```
firestoreConnect([
    {
      collection: "trainings",

  ])
```

while exampleB.js has the following codes of

```
 firestoreConnect([
    {
      collection: "trainings",
      orderBy: ["dateTime", "asc"],
      where:[["trainingName","==","abc123"]]

    }
  ])
```

When I first loaded exampleA.js, the trainings data are loaded randomly from the database(Firestore), as shown and highlighted in the upper part of image.

But, when I am moving to exampleB.js,I need the training data to be loaded in the ascending order of dateTime and filtered by trainingName as shown in the bottom part of the image.

The problem is when it is loading exampleB.js, the random order of data will be rendered first for a while(as they are already in the state.firestore.ordered.training in the prervious load of exampleA.js), before the sorted/ascending order of filtered data are rendered.

This really give a bad user interaction experiences and I do not know how to fix it. Is there any way to delete/clear the data in state.firestore.ordered everytime it is moving to new page? or is there a way to delay the render until state.firestore.unordered.data are fully updated? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you load example A if you don't need it? Why don't you just load example B in the order that you need it? Please clarify why you don't just fetch ordered data from firebase the first time.

Comment: Hi, I just edited my exampleB.js so I can give a better explanation. For the first time, I fetch unordered data in exampleA.js to display all trainings and their orders are not important. However, when I click a button which will link the user to exampleB.js, I would like to fetch  and display data only with tainingName of "abc123" in the ascending order of dateTime. But it will display the random order of trainings first before displaying the filtered trainings in ascending order.

Comment: If you have already fetched the data in example A it would make sense to sort the existing data clientside than issue a new network request for the exact same data. I suggest doing a client-side sort() or reduce() (if you only want the subset of name abc123) for this situation.

Comment: If you absolutely must issue two network requests then just manually clear the state field where you are storing 'trainings' data before you issue the second network request. You will need to share where and how you are clicking the button to link users to example B if you want help implementing that.

Comment: Thanks! It solves my problem with client-sdie sort(). And for learning purpose, may I know how to manually clear the state field? The "button" linking users to example B is as follow:

 <Link to="/exampleB"  >
      <div>button</div>
 </Link>

Comment: Basic idea is you store data in state. Render from data in state not from data coming directly from firebase. That way you can clear state before refreshing. You will need to show us where you are storing the data in state, where it is rendering and where this link button is in this context. A Link Tag suggest you are firing this event on a page transition. It's quite confusing. I suggest creating a new question for this. Please add link to the new question here and I will answer if I can  Please accept my answer below to help other people who have the same question as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already fetched the data in example A it would make more sense to sort the existing data clientside than issue a new network request for the exact same data. I suggest doing a client-side `sort()` or `reduce()` (reduce if you only want a subset of data, e.g. only items named abc123) for this situation.